# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Tags: java, spring, exception, jackson, objectmapper

Upgrading the spring version from 3.x to 5.x in the project. Already the project has objectmapper from org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper(1.9.11) and com.fasterxml.jackson.data-bind.ObjectMapper(2.11.0) both were used and in working condition with spring version(3.x).
Eclipselink is the jpa implementation currently using.
After upgrading the spring version to 5.x, it is showing the following error:
**Internal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper**

Is there any dependency conflict? if so how come it has worked in the spring old version? The online doc says org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper is superseded by jackson-data binder. But if so classNotFound exception should be thrown related to org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper right?
please help to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

With the Spring 5 and above the version issue arises.

As evident from the above exception the root cause of this exception is missing class InvalidDefinitionException.
This class has been introduced in jackson databind API since 2.9.0 version onwards.

To resolve this issue simply add jackson databind dependency with version 2.9.0 or above

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
       <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks @Java Team..but jackson-databind is already added and jar available in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am sure the defendency is included, but even if the dependency is included, we need ensure the JAR file containing ObjectMapper is on the classpath.

This usually happens automatically with build tools, but double-check if you're manually managing the classpath.

i was able to solve this error by changing the module-info file. What i noticed is, I imported jackson using the keyword requires static.

it should be imported using "requires" only